# Not importing pandas from a function

Tags: python, pandas, import, jupyter-notebook

The error is shown in the image.

[image: Jupyter notebook not importing pandas from function]

It is shown that the cells have been executed consecutively. Where is the error?

If I call pandas directly it functions ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think pandas is imported only on the scope of function.

Answer (score 4):

You imported pandas in a function which is sent to garbage when function is over.

Try importing outside the function